# Color of the Diagonal in a Heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm trying to interpret a heatmap I created with the following code:

```
csv <- read.csv("test.csv")
aggdata <-aggregate(csv[-1], list(csv[[1]]), sum)
row.names(aggdata) <- aggdata$Group.1
aggdata[["Group.1"]] = NULL
aggdata_matrix <- as.matrix(aggdata)
cor.mat <- cor(t(aggdata_matrix)) 
heatmap(cor.mat, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA)
```

[image: Heatmap]

The diagonal represents the similarity between the aggregated groups. So e.g. sports should be identical to sports and thus white. The same holds for politics and history.
However, I don't understand, why this isn't the case with art. As you can see in the left corner, the rectangle is not the same color as the remaining diagonal.

Why is this the case?

This is my example data:

```
doc1,word1,word2,word3,word4,word5,word6,word7,word8,word9,word10
POLITICS,8,1,3,8,5,0,0,3,4,4
SPORTS,4,5,3,4,2,5,3,3,0,7
HISTORY,3,0,4,3,0,3,8,3,3,1
SPORTS,5,7,3,8,6,4,5,6,3,4
ART,5,4,3,0,7,7,6,2,6,6
POLITICS,2,2,5,5,6,2,0,2,2,6
SPORTS,4,0,6,8,6,7,8,0,8,7
HISTORY,1,7,5,0,1,4,2,1,1,7
ART,0,8,3,3,8,6,3,1,3,6
SPORTS,6,7,3,2,6,7,2,1,1,7
POLITICS,8,0,2,7,0,2,6,5,3,1
POLITICS,7,0,4,2,0,3,8,1,1,3
```

Comment: Since `image(t(cor.mat))`, which `heatmap` allegedly calls, does *not* exhibit this behavior, your problem evidently is located within the `heatmap` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem--which can be found quickly by stepping through the execution of `heatmap` (issue the command `debug(heatmap)` first)--is that the code has standardized the rows by default.  Turn off this unwanted behavior by including `scale="none"` as an argument to `heatmap`.

[image: Figure]